# Why JWT Token contains algorithm used for encryption/signature

Tags: encryption, oauth, cryptography, authorization, jwt

What's the purpose of JWT Token containing an algorithm used for signature? The Client-side does not need that information and the server-side should already know this algorithm.

Comment: Let's say tomorrow a weakness is found in the existing encryption algorithm .. what to do ? How do you switch to new algorithm ?

Comment: Could the application be using different algorithms for different tokens? In that case how would it know what algorithm to use, since authentication is stateless and it doesn't store the algorithm for each token on the server side? I'm not sure if the use case for this exists, but it's only that I could think of. Someone downvote me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: This question is better asked on [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the "alg"-claim is mandatory by spec not just for [encrypted JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516#section-4.1.1) (JWE) but also for (just) [signed JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.1) (JWS) and [even unsecured JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-8.5).

A central reason for why referencing used cryptographic algorithms is a good idea is what RFC 7518 defines as ["Cryptographic Agility"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-8.5):

> Implementers should be aware that cryptographic algorithms become
> weaker with time.  As new cryptanalysis techniques are developed and
> computing performance improves, the work factor to break a particular
> cryptographic algorithm will be reduced.  Therefore, implementers and
> deployments must be prepared for the set of algorithms that are
> supported and used to change over time.  Thus, cryptographic
> algorithm implementations should be modular, allowing new algorithms
> to be readily inserted.

Being cryptographically agile basically means that your Auth-Server can make use of multiple algorithms at the same time. This e.g. allows graceful rollout of tokens signed and/ or encrypted with new/ different algorithms without breaking support of already issued tokens.

As JWTs are used in what I call [Stateless Authentication](https://www.jbspeakr.cc/purpose-jwt-stateless-authentication/), the Auth-Server ideally does not store any token state. Hence, the used algorithm needs to get stored as part of the tokens metadata within its header.